# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for creating only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have a `Post` model. I would like to let users create post comments while creating/updating a post by `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments`. However, I don't want to let users update comments by nested attributes.

Is there a way to do something like `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, create_only: true`?

Comment: Pretty interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use something like this accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject: :persisted? 
This will check, if Post object persisted or not. You also can replace persisted? with your custom method

Comment: Sorry, but I think you misread my question. I didn't mean to reject nested attributes for comments when the post is persisted. What I meant is only accepting nested attributes for creating comments.

Comment: Sorry,it was my mistake. But I think you can use method for reject_if which will check if comments_attributes have :id params or not.

Comment: Yeah, that what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can `reject_if` the `id` attribute is present:

```ruby
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['id'].present? }
```